# How to set a left position attribute using selectors in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, position

I am new to jquery and I want to set left and top position attribute of an image using selectors in jquery.
I have the following div:

```
#loadingGraph {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10000;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

I have search and found how to get the left value, but I didn't find the way to set it.
Can anyone help?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `css` method.

Set:

```
$('#loadingGraph').css('left', 'newValue');
```

Get:

```
var left = $('#loadingGraph').css('left');
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('#loadingGraph').css('left', '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://api.jquery.com/offset/.

Basic usage:

```
//Getter
var pos = $('#loadingGraph').offset();
//returns an object where X and Y are integral pixel coordinates
pos = {
    top: Y,
    left: X
}

//Setters
$('#loadingGraph').offset({
    top: 40,
    left: 200
});
$('#loadingGraph').offset( function () {
   return {
        top: resultOfSomeFunctionToCalculateTheTop(),
        left: resultOfSomeFunctionToCalculateTheTop()
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .css to set style of jQuery object

```
$('#loadingGraph').css({top:topvalue, left:leftvalue});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#loadingGraph').css('left','yourValue');
```

or

```
$('#loadingGraph').css({left: 'yourValue'});
```

**[Further Reference](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**